Kernel of the natural map $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$
I want to study the kernel of the natural map $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\to\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ given by reducing mod $n$ each entry of the matrix, let us call this group $G$. I heard this group is called the modular group. Of course, all elements of this group are of the form:
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$
where $a_{11},a_{22}\equiv 1\mod n$ and  $a_{12},a_{21}\equiv 0\mod n$. I claim that this group must be normally generated by a small set of matrices, probably something like
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
I want to prove whether $G=\langle\langle A,B\rangle\rangle$ or something similar but with other matrices of similar form. It is likely that this result is already known, but I was not able to find it.
Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Did you see this post, on the right margin?

These are no generators for $\Gamma(2)$? Take $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Furthermore $B$ can be normally generated by $A$ since $B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\1& 0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$.

@psl2Z So you say that $G$ is generated by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$? Can you provide a proof or a reference of this?

First find normal generators $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ for $G\cap \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $\left\langle\left\langle(A_i)_{i \in I}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle\right\rangle = G$.
In the general case $N$ not prime it seems that there is no explicit set of generators known for $G\cap \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. For this see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2757/generators-for-congruence-subgroups-of-sl-2.
For $N = 2$ it is known (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29700/generators-for-congruence-group-gamma2) that $G\cap\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle$.
Therefore $G = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle$.

Thanks, that was what I needed.
